# Read files in R using for loop causes error

Tags: r, for-loop

Hi iam having a list of files in "filenames' of length 300 ie, 300 files class of filenames is character
class. I tried to execute for loop like as follows:

```
 filenames=list.files(file.path(getwd(), directory), full.names=TRUE) ## directory is a folder name
 for (item in filenames) {print item)
```

Then

```
for (i in c(1:length(filenames)) {print i}
```

I basically want it to read using for loop. But it gives me unexpected symbol error Can anyone be of some help

Comment: I'm not sure how your code is related to reading files, but you have a missing parenthesis in your second line of code. Also, your code always runs in R. RStudio is simply an IDE (a "frontend").

Comment: Please include reproducible code. `print item` is not a valid R statement.

Comment: @Roland i have edited my question please have a look

Answer (score 1):

```
  for (item in filenames) {print (item))
```

This is working now. A paranthesis was required after print. I accidently followed python2.7 format

Thanks.